# Displaying rows as Columns in table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a Table Like Below

```
CREATE TABLE Statistics(Stat_Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
                        Period  VARCHAR(55),
                        Location VARCHAR(255),
                        Rate_per_SqFt INT)
```

The Datas in the Table are

```
INSERT INTO Statistics(Period, Location, Rate_per_SqFt)
                VALUES('June', 'Location A', 2500),
                      ('June', 'Location B', 2740),
                      ('June', 'Location C', 3200),
                      ('July', 'Location A', 2650),
                      ('July', 'Location B', 2800),
                      ('July', 'Location C', 3250),
                      ('August', 'Location A', 2750),
                      ('August', 'Location B', 2950),
                      ('August', 'Location C', 3230),
                      ('October', 'Location A', 2950),
                      ('October', 'Location B', 3950),
                      ('October', 'Location C', 3530);
```

I want the Rows for Particular Month Displayed in Output as Separate Columns as Below

```
 Period   Location A     Location B     Location C 
 June        2500          2740           3200
 July        2650          2800           3250
 August      2750          2950           3230
 October     2950          3950           3530
```

How can I do this using Query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT Period,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Location = 'Location A' THEN Rate_per_SqFt ELSE NULL END) `Location A`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Location = 'Location B' THEN Rate_per_SqFt ELSE NULL END) `Location B`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Location = 'Location C' THEN Rate_per_SqFt ELSE NULL END) `Location C`
FROM statistics
GROUP BY Period
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6bbc/1)

if you have **unknown** number of locations, a Dynamic SQL is preferred

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(CASE WHEN Location = ''',
      Location,
      ''' then Rate_per_SqFt ELSE NULL end) AS ',
      CONCAT('`',Location,'`')
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM statistics;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT Period, ', @sql, ' 
                   FROM Statistics 
                   GROUP BY Period');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6bbc/2)

Comment: How do i get the Column Names in PHP

Comment: what do you mean by column names?

Comment: Thanks for reply so Soon. In case of procedure  you used I am not sure how many columns its going to come in output. So how should I get this thing in PHP